# Routes in Codeigniter - Automatically

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, url-rewriting

I have a problem with Codeigniter routes. I would like to all registered users on my site gets its own "directory", for example: `www.example.com/username1`, `www.example.com/username2`. This "directory" should map to the controller "polica", method "ogled", parameter "username1".

If I do like this, then each controller is mapped to this route: "polica/ogled/parameter". It's not OK:

```
$route["(:any)"] = "polica/ogled/$1";
```

This works, but I have always manually entered info in `routes.php`:

```
$route["username1"] = "polica/ogled/username1";
```

How do I do so that this will be automated?

**UPDATE:**
For example, I have controller with name `ads`. For example, if you go to `www.example.com/ads/`
there will be listed ads. If you are go to `www.example.com/username1` there are listed ads by user `username1`. There is also controller `user`, `profile`, `latest`,...

My Current `routes.php`:

```
$route['oglasi'] = 'oglasi';
$route['(:any)'] = "polica/ogled/$1"
$route['default_controller'] = 'domov';
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

I solved problem with this code:

```
$route['oglasi/(:any)'] = 'oglasi/$1';
$route['(:any)'] = "polica/ogled/$1"
$route['default_controller'] = 'domov';
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

Regards, Mario

Comment: Brilliant! I just did this with the default controller and it works there as well.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem with your route is that by using :any you match, actually...ANY route, so you're pretty much stuck there.
I think you might have two solutions:

1)You can selectively re-route all your sites controller individually, like:

```
$route['aboutus'] = "aboutus";
$route['where-we-are'] = "whereweare";
//And do this for all your site's controllers
//Finally:
$route['(:any)'] = "polica/ogled/$1";
```

All these routes must come BEFORE the ANY, since they are read in the order they are presented, and if you place the :any at the beginning it will happily skip all the rest.

**EDIT after comment:**

What I mean is, if you're going to match against ANY segment, this means that you cannot use any controller at all (which is, by default, the first URI segment), since the router will always re-route you using your defined law. 
In order to allow CI to execute other controllers (whatever they are, I just used some common web pages, but can be literally everything), you need to allow them by excluding them from the re-routing. And you can achieve this by placing them before your ANY rule, so that everytime CI passed through your routing rules it parses first the one you "escaped", and ONLY if they don't match anything it found on the URL, it passes on to the :ANY rule.

I know that this is a code verbosity nonetheless, but they'll surely be less than 6K as you said.
Since I don't know the actual structure of your URLs and of your web application, it's the only solution that comes to my mind. If you provide further information, such as how are shaped the regular urls of your app, then I can update my answer

**/end edit**

This is not much a pratical solution, because it will require a lot of code, but if you want a design like that it's the only way that comes to my mind.
Also, consider you can use regexes as the $route index, but I don't think it can work here, as your usernames are unlikely matchable in this fashion, but I just wanted to point out the possibility.

**OR**

2) You can change your design pattern slightly, and assign another route to usernames, something along the line of

```
$route['user/(:any)'] = "polica/ogled/$1";
```

This will generate quite pretty (and semantic) URLs nonetheless, and will avoid all the hassle of escaping the other routes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I can not use your second solution because my client want's to have username after domain name. I don't understand your first solution. Can you please explain it to me on my case? My goal is, to solve this problem with less code. Now, I have in my `routes.php` file about 6000 rows - I don't like this :/

Comment: @Puzo I updated my answer with some explanation of the first solution. And yes, 6000 routes are definitely too much.

Comment: I updated my first post - question.. Do you need more information? What kind?

Comment: Now I have code in `routes.php` in my first post - question. Now I can not access to controller `oglas` and I put it before username rules..

Comment: @Puzo sorry for being late. I see you solved your problems. Just one thing: as the manual state, you should put your custom routes AFTER the default ones, so after 'default_controller' and '404_ovverride'. For the rest, I see you got the point, hope everything works now

Comment: No problem! Thank you @Damien Pirsy. Yes everything works fine now! :)

Answer (score 2):

view this:
http://www.web-and-development.com/codeigniter-minimize-url-and-remove-index-php/
which includes remove index.php/remove 1st url segment/remove 2st url sigment/routing automatically.it will very helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this same problem very recently. I created something that worked for me this way:

Define a "redirect" controller with a [remap](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#remapping) method. This will allow you to gather the requests sent to the contoller with any proceeding variable string into one function. So if a request is made to `http://yoursite/jeff/` or `http://yoursite/jamie` it won't hit those methods but instead hit `http://yoursite/` remap function. (even if those methods/names don't exist and even if you have an index function, it supersedes it). In the _Remap method you could define a conditional switch which then works with the rest of your code re-directing the user any way you want.

You should then define this re-direct controller as the default one and set up your routes like so:

```
$route['(.*)'] = "redirect/index/$1";
$route['default_controller'] = "redirect";
```

This is at first a bit of a problem because this will basically force everything to be re-directed to this controller no matter what and ultimately through this `_remap` switch.

But what you could do is define the rules/routes that you don't want to abide to this condition above those route statements.

i.e

```
$route['myroute'] = "myroute";
$route['(.*)'] = "redirect/index/$1";
$route['default_controller'] = "redirect";
```

I found that this produces a nice system where I can have as many variable users as are defined where I'm able to redirect them easily based on what they stand for through one controller.

Comment: Hmm.. So if I understand correctly, I should define all my controllers in `routes.php` file and then on the bottom I define redirect rule? Affects this on performance of page?

Comment: @Puzo Reading your comment, that's pretty much what I tried to say in my answer..

Comment: @Chamilyan How can i replace # with / in url with routing

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be declaring an array with your intenal controllers and redirect everything else to the user controller like this in your routes.php file from codeigniter:

```
$controllers=array('admin', 'user', 'blog', 'api');
if(array_search($this->uri->segment(1), $controllers)){
    $route['.*'] = "polica/ogled/$1";
}
```