# .htaccess - Changing the look of a URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I'm having trouble trying to figure out htaccess rewrites.

I'm using codeigniter for a project and im crafting the urls like so

```
http://www.website.com/profile/u/crispybenz
```

where the last segment of the url is the users unique username.

I want people to be able to access it using

```
http://website.com/crispybenz
```

Is that possible?

Comment: `im crafting the urls like so` Does it mean that you already have some RewriteRules? you have to show them too.

Comment: Sorry, no i dont have any current rules ... its like that as codeigniter uses www.website.com/controller/function/username

Comment: Vote to close: [Exact Doop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618633/routes-in-codeigniter-automatically)

Comment: I don't think it is exact duplicate [Routes in Codeigniter - Automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618633/routes-in-codeigniter-automatically) . This question is about rewrite the url using **htaccess** and not using the route in that question. It could of cause an option using the route feature in codeigniter to achieve the desired result in this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using CodeIgnitor routing rules. check out their [official documents here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work in an htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /profile/u/$1 [L]
```

If the folder doesnt exist it will try http://website.com/profile/u/NONEXISTENT_FOLDER