# How to build CodeIgniter site correctly

Tags: php, codeigniter, module, codeigniter-routing

I'm building a website using CodeIgnitier.

My problem is how can I use the MVC pattern **inside** a webpage.
Let's say I have a controller called "Settings", Within this page I want to divide the settings into categories, with tabs, like "System", "User" and so on.

I know how to do this in the usual way, something like "settings?tab=system" and then load the proper view according to the tab selected. But I want to make a separate MVC pattern for this settings page, is it possible? and how?

Comment: http://phpmaster.com/untangling-mvc-with-codeigniter/

Answer (score 1):

Basically the thing you are looking for is can be controlled using routes.ini or Route.php. The tab can be your querystring. Settings can be a controller and u can have an action called index which can be controlling it.

Comment: Do you have any link that explain it in more details?

Comment: This might be helpful  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618633/routes-in-codeigniter-automatically

Comment: This might be more helpful http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Comment: Thanks. But is it the only way? is it possible to do this with pure MVC approach?

Comment: Well if you look at pure concept of MVC routing is used to hide the main url like hiding /controllername/actionname. So I wud say use routes as it hides your actual code location. Other way what u want is u directly type in ur address bar as controllername/actionname/?querystring