# Remove controller name from url using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would like to remove our welcome contoroller from url 
how to remove index using codegniter

```
$route['^(:any)(/:any)?$'] = "welcome/$0";
```

but my links are

```
<?php echo site_url('welcome/about'); ?>
<?php echo site_url('welcome/index'); ?>
<?php echo site_url('welcome/contact'); ?>
```

When click this link the url is same welcome/contact and error page occurred my $route only works `localhost/mydomain/index` when click any url `localhost/mydomain/welcome/contact`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Routes in Codeigniter - Automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618633/routes-in-codeigniter-automatically)

Comment: When you are directing to a index function you don't need to include it `<?php echo site_url('welcome'); ?>` not `<?php echo site_url('welcome/index'); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

if you ONLY want to remove **'welcome'** from the URL,

you could do:

`$route['(:any)'] = "welcome/$1"`

**Others:**

You can define a custom route in `config/routes.php` - for example:

```
$route['about'] = 'name_controller/about';

Then, http://example.com/about
goes to http://example.com/name_controller/about
```

See [Hiding the controller’s method name in the URL?](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/52675/#257234) in the CI forums for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can add route in `config/routes.php`

For Ex :

```
$route['about'] = 'welcome/about';
$route['index'] = 'welcome/index';
$route['contact'] = 'welcome/contact';
```

You can used Like :

```
localhost/mydomain/about
localhost/mydomain/index
localhost/mydomain/contact
```

Please set Your Site URL Like :

```
<a href="<?= base_url() ?>about">Abouts<a/>
<a href="<?= base_url() ?>index">Index<a/>
<a href="<?= base_url() ?>contact">Contact<a/>
```

Comment: what about site_url()

Comment: Please check update answer now. and you can visit for set base URL settings. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792268/how-to-set-proper-codeigniter-base-url